# Android, Java, Listen for KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE from a Service?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that runs as a service in the background. I am trying to add functionality to it that will look for an event from a BT headset, specifically KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE. If that even is triggered, I would like to run a specific function (just for an example, display a Toast message). I need to be accomplish this with the screen on or off and not interfere with the intended target of pausing/playing music (ie, if Spotify or Pandora are running & playing music, still need it to pause it button is pressed). I have tried multiple ways of accomplishing this (a few are https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/mediabuttons & https://riptutorial.com/android/example/21618/receiving-and-handling-button-events plus several other methods) but no method I have tried will ever trigger on the button being pressed. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: try `KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK`.

Comment: No luck with that either.